# how to store NSMutableArray in NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Please tell me how can i store  `NSMutableArray` into `NSUserDefaults`.

I have an array called data(`NSArray`).I want to add this array in `NSMutableArray` called `mArray`.

```
[mArray addObject:data];
[prefs setObject:mArray forkey:@"test"];
[prefs synchronize];
```

& want to store `mArray` values in `NSUserDefaults`.
Please tell me how can i store & retrive these values.
above code is storing only last value not appending value in `NSUserDefaults`.

Thanks

Answer (score 21):

You can't.  See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html, in particular :

> Values returned from NSUserDefaults
>   are immutable, even if you set a
>   mutable object as the value. For
>   example, if you set a mutable string
>   as the value for "MyStringDefault",
>   the string you later retrieve using
>   stringForKey: will be immutable.

Instead, make a mutableCopy of the array you retrieve from NSUserDefaults, add your object, then set your new array back in.